ImportError: tools/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/math.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type
I am using Python 3.9 on Linux. The python installation structure looks like:
/tools/python/bin - containing python executable
/tools/python/lib/libpython3.9.so 
/tools/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/*

I am linking a x.so with libpython.so and trying to run it. And when I run a simple python script test.py(present in /share/python) that looks like:
import unittest
import math

class Test_2(unittest.TestCase):
def test_distance(self):
    self.assertAlmostEqual(box1.distance(box2), math.sqrt(2))

def suite() :
        suite = unittest.TestSuite()
        suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(Test_2))
        return suite

It simply gives the following error in the log:
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/share/python/test.py", line 3, in <module>
import math
ImportError: /tools/python/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/math.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type

I have set PYTHONPATH as : /share/python and PYTHONHOME as : /tools/python
And appended LD_LIBRARYPATH with /tools/python/lib so that it finds libpython3.9.so
But still get the above import error:  "math.so: undefined symbol: PyFloat_Type"
Can someone pls help me in this issue.
Following is the output:
[abc@xyz01 ~]$ ldd /tools/python/bin/python
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc281ce000)
    libpython3.9.so.1.0 => /tools/python/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0 (0x00007f28887d8000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f28885af000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f288838f000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f288818b000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2887f87000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2887c05000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2887840000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2888b6a000)

[abc@xyz01 ~]$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/share/python
[abc@xyz01 ~]$ echo $PYTHONHOME
/tools/python
[abc@xyz01 bin]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
tools/python/lib:/build/tools/libstdc+/lib64:/build/tools/lib/64bit:/build/tools/lib:/build81/tools/Qt/v5/64bit/lib:/build/tools/boost/lib/64bit/:/usr/lib64:/build/tools/lib/64bit/RHEL/RHEL8:/build/tools/lib/64bit/RHEL/RHEL7:/build81/tools/libstdc++/lib64:/build81/tools/lib/64bit:/usr/X11R6/lib:/lib:/usr/lib


ldd /tools/python/bin/python? Please show an output of environment (the 3 mentioned variables), command line ran and the error. How did you build your Python instance? Any errors in the logs? The error text is strange as math module is builtin for a long time.

Appended the requested output in the question as it was too long,

Additionally when I run the script, I get the following error as well in the log: [3383862:3383942:0415/043005.777458:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(960)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101

"I am linking a x.so with libpython.so " how?

I am doing this via Makefile of the module x. Effectively in the log, in the command line it expands to: @=== Loading lni64/libx.so: ...
g++ -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -m64 -pipe -fPIC -Wl,--no-undefined -O2  -ffloat-store -L /tools/python/lib -L /tools/boost/lib/64bit -lpython3.9 -lboost_python38 -o /lni64/libx.so

-lpython3.9 -lboost_python38 huh? why are you linking boost for python 3.8?

It is required as I am using Boost python APIs for importing python modules in C++ code. Hence linking both. I was able to resolve this issue when I added python dependency in the Makefile of the executable that was running. Also the issue gets resolved when I use LD_PRELOAD env var to the python .so. However the former option is cleaner than using LD_PRELOAD.
